# css transition end effect for toogle vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I made a box transition while it get bigger, how do I still make it have same transition effect on close cause it closes sharply.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div @click="biggerbox = !biggerbox;" class="box" :class="{'biggerbox':biggerbox}"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data() {
    return {
      biggerbox: false
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

```
<style scoped>
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  width: 90px;
}

.biggerbox {
  background-color: red;
  height: 180px;
  width: 190px;
  display: flex;
   transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
</style>
```

This is the link to the code sand box
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dew-0pm34?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:338-582

Answer (score 1):

You should add the transition properties to the `.box` class like so:

```
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  width: 90px;

  transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;
}
```

You do this since this is the class that is there no matter the state, so the transition is still present when you remove the other class.

Here's a bonus tip: you can use a single class attribute on your element like this:

```
<div
  @click="biggerbox = !biggerbox;"
  :class="['box', {'biggerbox':biggerbox}]"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you remove the .biggerbox class you lose the transition.

just add the transition to the .box class instead

```
.box {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px;
  width: 90px;
}
```